# Qt 5.5 and OpenGL: QVertexArrayObject::create() calls QPainter::drawimage()?

Tags: qt, opengl, vertex-array-object

I understand that for any of the Qt OpenGL convenience classes to correctly be initialized and used, they must be called with a valid current context. So, I designed my classes to be initialized from my overloaded `QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()` function, in which the documentation states the context is created and made current (albeit without a framebuffer).

However, when `initializeGL()` attempts to initialize one of my subclasses `MeshObject`, specifically calling the function `QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::create()`, the program crashes with the message

`Read access violation at 0x0`
Going through with a debugger, note the call stack:

[image]

There are calls being made to QPainter::drawImage, which would surely fail as there is no framebuffer present.

But why is there a `QPainter::drawImage` call happening when I try to create a vertexArrayObject? Surely this function should have no involvement with painting to the screen.

ALthough the documentation also states that QOpenGLVertexArrayObjects will only work on some OpenGL ES 2.0 platforms, `vbuffer.create()` causes exactly the same scenario to occur, and I've already used `QOpenGLVertexArrayObjects` on this exact machine on a previous project with absolutely no problems.

Complete stack trace:

```
0   QPainter::drawImage Qt5Guid     0x58292a56  
1   QPainter::drawImage Qt5Guid     0x5829203c  
2   MeshState::initBuffers  meshobject.cpp  71  0x2fb793    
3   SceneObject::setupObjects   sceneobject.cpp 18  0x2fa1eb    
4   SceneObject::initialize sceneobject.cpp 12  0x2fa12f    
5   OpenGLWidget::initializeGL  openglwidget.cpp    34  0x2f8ecf    
6   QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x587a9859  
7   QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x587a86da  
8   QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x58770104  
9   QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x587a8850  
10  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x5872548e  
11  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x587235f5  
12  QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource  Qt5Cored        0x591b6b47  
13  QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource  Qt5Cored        0x591bf379  
14  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x5877a3a3  
15  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x5877a618  
16  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x5876be41  
17  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x5876c0bb  
18  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x58779441  
19  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x5877a62e  
20  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x5876be41  
21  QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBar Qt5Widgetsd     0x5876c0bb  
22  main    main.cpp    10  0x2f3419    
23  WinMain qtmain_win.cpp  113 0x2fdcdd    
24  __tmainCRTStartup   crtexe.c    618 0x2fd0bf    
25  WinMainCRTStartup   crtexe.c    466 0x2fce7d    
26  BaseThreadInitThunk KERNEL32        0x772e38f4  
27  __RtlUserThreadStart    ntdll       0x77865de3  
28  _RtlUserThreadStart ntdll       0x77865dae
```

Comment: What is the complete stack trace?

Comment: @peppe added stacktrace up to the exception

Comment: Can you please right click on the stack trace and use the "copy" function instead of screenshotting it? That backtrace makes absolutely no sense. Maybe valgrind your app?

Comment: Your stack trace looks corrupt.